# Is it possible to find out if the android widget is placed on lock screen or home screen?

Tags: android

Is it possible to find out if the android widget is placed on lock screen or home screen?
I'd imagine it's somewhere in the broadcast provider so I can find out how user is using it on 4.2+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the relevant snippets from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen):

"You can detect whether your widget is on the keyguard (lockscreen) or home screen by calling `getAppWidgetOptions()` to get the widget's options as a Bundle.

The returned bundle will include the key `OPTION_APPWIDGET_HOST_CATEGORY`, whose value will be one of `WIDGET_CATEGORY_HOME_SCREEN` or `WIDGET_CATEGORY_KEYGUARD`. "

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
int widgetId;
Bundle myOptions = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions (widgetId);

// Get the value of OPTION_APPWIDGET_HOST_CATEGORY
int category = myOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_HOST_CATEGORY, -1);

// If the value is WIDGET_CATEGORY_KEYGUARD, it's a lockscreen widget
boolean isKeyguard = category == AppWidgetProviderInfo.WIDGET_CATEGORY_KEYGUARD;
```

"Once you know the widget's category, you can optionally load a different base layout, set different properties, and so on. For example:"

```
int baseLayout = isKeyguard ? R.layout.keyguard_widget_layout : R.layout.widget_layout;
```

Comment: when i try using this and run on a non 4.2 device i get the error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions

Comment: @user1492955, If a device is below 4.2 (below api level 17), then it can not have a widget on its lockscreen (since that feature was not introduced then), so then you can automatically assume it was launched from the homescreen instead. In my next comment is the code you need to add to exclude everything below api level 17.

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) { } else { }